# PHP event calendar disable "add event" on a weekend

Tags: php, events, calendar, disabled-control

I have put this [PHP event calendar](http://www.phpcodeworks.com/pec) on my development system. How can I disable adding event on a Saturday or a Sunday? :) Do you think this has to do with this code?

```
  function dayPullDown($day)
  {
echo "<select name=\"day\">\n";

$selected[$day] = ' selected="selected"';

for($i=1;$i <= 31; $i++) {
    $sel = (isset($selected[$i])) ? $selected[$i] : "";
    echo "  <option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
}
echo "</select>\n\n";}
```

Comment: Check to see if the date is a weekend and don't put it in the dropdown if it is.

Comment: You should consider using the PHP DateTime object, instead of hardcoded "31" days. What happens on months with less than 31 days? http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: i dont know how to do it :(

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through 31 days, you could use PHP's `datetime` class and check if today is a weekday (not a weekend) and display the dropdown menu only if your condition is satisfied:

```
$date = new DateTime();
if($date->format('N') < 6) {
    echo "<select name=\"day\">\n";
    $sel = (isset($selected[$i])) ? $selected[$i] : "";
    echo "  <option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
    echo "</select>\n\n";
}
```

Comment: where will i put this?

Comment: it says undefined i variable

Comment: @hehehe: This should go inside your loop.  `$i` is defined only in the scope of that loop.

Comment: like this? 

function dayPullDown($day)
{
 echo "<select name=\"day\">\n";

 $selected[$day] = ' selected="selected"';

 for($i=1;$i <= 31; $i++) {
  $date = new DateTime();
   if($date->format('N') < 6) {
   echo "<select name=\"day\">\n";
   $sel = (isset($selected[$i])) ? $selected[$i] : "";
   echo "  <option value=\"$i\"$sel>$i</option>\n";
 }
 echo "</select>\n\n";
}